# How can I get the baseurl of site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri, httprequest

I want to write a little helper method which returns the base URL of the site. This is what I came up with:

```
public static string GetSiteUrl()
{
    string url = string.Empty;
    HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    if (request.IsSecureConnection)
        url = "https://";
    else
        url = "http://";

    url += request["HTTP_HOST"] + "/";

    return url;
}
```

Is there any mistake in this, that you can think of? Can anyone improve upon this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933662/in-asp-net-what-is-the-quickest-way-to-get-the-base-url-for-a-request

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my webapp's base URL in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288046/how-can-i-get-my-webapps-base-url-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 369, accepted):

Try this:

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + 
    Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
```

Comment: This is the only answer I've found that deals with the case where a site an application which is a child of a top level website in IIS.

Comment: string.Format("{0}{1}/", Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/'))

Comment: Request.Url.Scheme does not always work when you have internal http configured and SSL termination set up for https internally on a server, but running https* outside. To get around this, I simply made an environment specific AppSetting Key "UrlScheme" with value of either "http" or "https" based on where the website resides. This setting in the web.config can be accessed by ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]

Comment: This doesn't take into account load balancing, where decryption occurs, or forward proxies. You can end up with an incorrect address using this, so be careful and know where your website had been deployed to.

Comment: $"{System.Web.HttpContext.‌​Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}{System.Web.HttpContext.Cur‌​rent.Request.ApplicationPath?.TrimEnd('/')}/";

Comment: Even though this answer has 362 votes, When Application is starting, `Request` does not exists generally on any routine that runs before any request arrive from user e.g. when code in Application_start or static class methods, handler registration code ...

Answer (score 176):

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

That's it ;)

Comment: This doesn't work for Virtual or Application Path. You should use Request.ApplicationPath in addition to the left part.

Comment: base url is httpx://domain.com:[port]/ you must add app path yourself to this solution

Answer (score 10):

The popular `GetLeftPart` solution is not supported in the PCL version of `Uri`, unfortunately. `GetComponents` is, however, so if you need portability, this should do the trick:

```
uri.GetComponents(
    UriComponents.SchemeAndServer | UriComponents.UserInfo, UriFormat.Unescaped);
```

Answer (score 7):

To me, @warlock's looks like the best answer here so far, but I've always used this in the past;

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(
    UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.UriEscaped)
```

Or in a WebAPI controller;

```
string baseUrl = Url.Request.RequestUri.GetComponents(
    UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped)
```

which is handy so you can choose what escaping format you want. I'm not clear why there are two such different implementations, and as far as I can tell, this method and @warlock's return the exact same result in this case, but it looks like `GetLeftPart()` would also work for non server Uri's like `mailto` tags for instance.

Comment: returns invalid url for cases where you are behind ngrok tunnel and https

Answer (score 7):

This is a much more fool proof method.

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
```

Comment: @Daniel call won't return simply `/` if you host in some application domain e.g http://yourserver/yourapplicationname/yourrootpath

Comment: @vibs2006 yea its kind of an ambigous question

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the answers above doesn't consider when the site is not in the root of the website.

This is a for WebApi controller:

```
string baseUrl = (Url.Request.RequestUri.GetComponents(
                    UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped).TrimEnd('/') 
                 + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath).TrimEnd('/') ;
```

Comment: From within a controller use Configuration.VirtualPathRoot as it is host independent.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what Warlock wrote, I found that the virtual path root is needed if you aren't hosted at the root of your web. (This works for MVC Web API controllers)

```
String baseUrl = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) 
+ Configuration.VirtualPathRoot;
```

Answer (score 4):

I go with

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
```

Comment: This will add the protocol:  (HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"] == "off"
                                ? "http://" : "https://")
                             + HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
Request.Url.OriginalString.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "") + Request.ApplicationPath;
```

- **Request.Url.OriginalString**: return the complete path same as browser showing.
- **Request.Url.PathAndQuery**: return the (complete path) - (domain name + PORT).
- **Request.ApplicationPath**: return "/" on hosted server and "application name" on local IIS deploy.

So if you want to access your domain name do consider to include the application name in case of:

1. IIS deployment
2. If your application deployed on the sub-domain.

====================================

For the dev.x.us/web

it return this
strong text

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following code from Application_Start

`String baseUrl = Path.GetDirectoryName(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString);`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```
string.Format("{0}://{1}", Request.url.Scheme, Request.url.Host);
```

Comment: Please explain your code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: The Port component is missing

Answer (score -2):

you could possibly add in the port for non port 80/SSL?

something like:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"].ToString() != "80" && HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"].ToString() != "443")
            {
                port = String.Concat(":", HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"].ToString());
            }
```

and use that in the final result?

Comment: `Request.Url.Authority` will include the port number if it's non-standard