# Get url of a different another page from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to create a verification email where the user can click on the link but I don't see a way to get the url of the page from code.

I see that

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

can be used for the current page but not the verification page that I want to link to.

The code behind for the verification page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirm = Request.QueryString("confirm")

    //check the confirm string and verify user
    ...
}
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413510/1139830) describes how to get the base web address. Assuming you know the path to the verification page, it's a matter of concatenating the strings (or using the Uri class to do that for you).

Comment: What is your verification page?

Comment: I was thinking that there is a better way but I will do that if there isn't one. I'm not sure what you mean but it's a page that get a confirmation query string and its path is "~/Pages/Verification"

Comment: what roman is asking @Danson is where is the actual code behind meaning your source code ..don't just post a single line of code and expect us to know where in your code you are using it show all relevant code that pertains to your current issue

Comment: I didn't think it pertains to the problem since my problem is getting the user a link to the page and the verification page doesn't really have anything yet. The page right now get a query string on page load and will confirm that it is correct and mark the user as verified. I edited in what I have in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current Url in a ViewState and in your AuthenticationPage, call this ViewState.

In your current page:

```
 ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

And in AuthenticationPage, you can get the value:

```
var previousPageUrl = (string)ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"];
```

Comment: I want to do it the other way around. I want to get the url of the AuthenticationPage from the current page.

Comment: Only possible this way if you create the URL.

Comment: @Danson if you know the URL of the AuthenticationPage you can navigate to it from any page within your solution.. are you familiar with how to `Redirect`

Comment: Yes, I want to get the link so that I can put it in an email to send like in a typical account verification email.