# What is the ASP.NET Core MVC equivalent to Request.RequestURI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I found a [blog post](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/) that shows how to "shim" familiar things like HttpResponseMessage back into ASP.NET Core MVC, but I want to know what's the new native way to do the same thing as the following code in a REST Post method in a Controller:

```
// POST audit/values
[HttpPost]
public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    var NewEntity = _repository.InsertFromString(value);

    var msg = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created);
    msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + NewEntity.ID.ToString());
    return msg;

}
```

In an ASP.NET Core MVC project, I can't seem to get Request.RequestUri.

I tried inspecting Request, and I was able to make a function like this:

```
private string UriStr(HttpRequest Request)
{
    return Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host + Request.Path; // Request.Path has leading /
}
```

So I could write `UriStr(Request)` instead. But I'm not sure that's right. I feel like I'm hacking my way around, and not using this correctly.

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413466/how-can-i-get-the-baseurl-of-site) for earlier non-Core ASP.NET MVC versions asks how to get the base url of the site.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A cleaner way would be to use a `UriBuilder`:

```
private static Uri GetUri(HttpRequest request)
{
    var builder = new UriBuilder();
    builder.Scheme = request.Scheme;
    builder.Host = request.Host.Value;
    builder.Path = request.Path;
    builder.Query = request.QueryString.ToUriComponent();
    return builder.Uri;
}
```

(not tested, the code might require a few adjustments)

Comment: If this is the only way to do it, then it's true that they left out capabilities that people used before, when redesigning? Have you seen other similar omissions yet?

Comment: @WarrenP Of course they left a lot of things about. It's basically rewritten from the ground up. And, it's still in beta.

Comment: Uris may also contain usernames and passwords, which are not accounted for in this snippet.

Comment: also doesn't handle port numbers in the host. use: `builder.Host = request.Host.Host; builder.Port = request.Host.Port ?? -1;`

Answer (score 100):

Personally, I use :

```
new Uri(request.GetDisplayUrl())
```

- `GetDisplayUrl` fully un-escaped form (except for the QueryString)
- `GetEncodedUrl` - fully escaped form suitable for use in HTTP headers

These are extension method from the following namespace : `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions`

Comment: That seems nice and clean.

Comment: elegant one! :+1

Comment: This certainly looks a lot cleaner, and more likely to handle the edge cases that a home-made solution might overlook. However, there is one thing about this that raises a red flag for me. Its purpose is only for display. From the comments:

> Returns the combined components of the request URL in a fully un-escaped form
> (except for the QueryString) suitable only for display. This format should not
> be used in HTTP headers or other HTTP operations.

I don't know what display-specific functionality there is, but it might not play nicely with the Uri constructor.

Comment: After writing all that, I now see there's a more appropriate method in the same package: GetEncodedUrl.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a working code. This is based off @Thomas Levesque answer which didn't work well when the request is from a custom port.

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static Uri ToUri(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        var hostComponents = request.Host.ToUriComponent().Split(':');

        var builder = new UriBuilder
        {
            Scheme = request.Scheme,
            Host = hostComponents[0],
            Path = request.Path,
            Query = request.QueryString.ToUriComponent()
        };

        if (hostComponents.Length == 2)
        {
            builder.Port = Convert.ToInt32(hostComponents[1]);
        }

        return builder.Uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out for the request.Path property. At present it seems to have a bug and always returns "/" whether or not the application is deployed to a virtual application.

Comment: Uris may also contain usernames and passwords, which are not accounted for in this snippet.