# How can I replace Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) for .NET Core View class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to migrate few View classes into .NET Core from .NET and I am having an issue with the lack of "Request" class methods. The following question might be related to my situation but I wasn't sure how to use UriBuilder or any of the other answer for this purpose. I wanted to ask something more specific and a little different.

[What is the ASP.NET Core MVC equivalent to Request.RequestURI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617345/what-is-the-asp-net-core-mvc-equivalent-to-request-requesturi)

My specific code is as follows:

```
<form id="contactUs" method="post" action="@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Action("ContactUsFormSubmit")" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Specifically I need to replace the `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` part of the code as I believe that it is not an available package for .NET Core.

Is there a replacement for .NET Core to get the "Authority" part of the Url? Could I be missing a simple reference etc due to my lack of experience in .NET/.NET Core?

Comment: Why do you even need that ? Why not just put the action method name and controller name ? Won't that work ?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure if it would work, I am fairly new to .NET Core. I assume that I could not do the same for this code though: `if (jQuery == undefined) loadjsfile("@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js");
    loadjsfile("@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
    loadjsfile("@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
    loadjsfile("@Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)/Scripts/contactusform.js");`

Comment: I would be happy to read a link or research a particular concept which could explain about a particular replacement using tag helpers and such but like in my previous comment, I also have it in a function. Please let me know if there is an article/book that could be useful for this situation!

Comment: I cannot give a complete answer to both the GetLeftPart and the Request in a Controller, but for the GetLeftPart, you can use GetComponents. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27473521/154480

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [GetComponents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the Uri class.  This should work for your case:

```
Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.StrongAuthority, UriFormat.Unescaped)
```