# Converting Request.RequestUri to ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jsgrid

What is the ASP.NET Core MVC equivalent to Request.RequestURI?

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET Core implementation of [JSGrid](http://js-grid.com/). The example provided they provide is pre-Core so I am having some problems converting the source code to ASP.NET Core.

Getting stuck on converting one last error on `Request.RequestUri.Query`

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617345/what-is-the-asp-net-core-mvc-equivalent-to-request-requesturi) but couldn't figure out how it applied to my case and it's also 3 years old.  I'm hoping that Microsoft has provided a new `using` which will handle `RequestUri` by now but I can't seem to find it.

Here's my controller so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Deviation.Data;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web;

namespace Deviation.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class JSGridController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DeviationContext _context;

        public JSGridController(DeviationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IEnumerable<object> Get()
        {
            ClientFilter filter = GetFilter();

            var result = _context.MissedDeliveries.Where(c =>
                (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Delivery) || c.Delivery.Contains(filter.Delivery))
            );

            return result.ToArray();
        }

        private ClientFilter GetFilter()
        {
            NameValueCollection filter = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);

            return new ClientFilter
            {
                Delivery = filter["Delivery"],
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks to anyone who could provide a bit of guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `HttpContext.Request.Query` :

```
var q = HttpContext.Request.Query;
var deliveries = q["Delivery"];
var delivery = q["Myquery"].FirstOrDefault();
```